# Groovy install in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to install Groovy in Ubuntu 14.04 using the ROS repository, instead of compiling from source? I ask since most all of our code is in Groovy (rosmake) but the device running ROS requires Ubuntu 14.04 due to hardware drivers/configuration, etc.?
Thanks for all the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186676/groovy-install-in-ubuntu-14.04/) by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-15**:
Dambrosio, hello.

I do not have an answer for you, but this was one of my objectives; to test groovy on 14,04. It is not a matter of working or not, but rather of being supported or not. So far, it is an unsupported platform, but go for it. If you have the means, test on a VM with 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well what do you know... Same question a few minutes earlier.

http://answers.ros.org/question/186649/groovy-on-ubuntu-1404/

It helps to know what hardware/platform we are talking about. x86 installs and ARM have different statuses.

---

Originally posted by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) with karma: 255 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) on 2014-07-15**:
This is a AMD64 platform.

**Comment by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) on 2014-07-16**:
Would this be the link for installing from source: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source? I will step through this today and let you know what the outcome is. Thanks for the responses.

**Comment by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) on 2014-07-16**:
I got to step 2.1.2 Resolving Dependencies and ran into issues running: rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
I get errors stating: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies. I tried to adding the --os. Any advice?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-18**:
You probably ran into this issue? https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4792